# SharePoint SOAP service GetListItem with respect to updated date?

Tags: iphone, sharepoint

Right now I am working on a project to fetch data from a SharePoint list using SOAP API. I tried and successfully fetches the complete list, but now I want to fetch some specific data that is updated after a specific date.

Is this possible to fetch such data using SOAP query. I can see last update filed when I view single item at the bottom. Is this some how possible to use that filed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last found the answer,

The last update date and time can be retrieved from the list column "Modified".
The soap response will have the value in the attribute "ows_Modified".

Muhammad Usman

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the Web Services to do lot of things just like filtering a list result. I don't know which language you use, but with JavaScript you can look at these two frameworks that should help you:

- http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/ : easy way to create your queries (I created it)
- http://spservices.codeplex.com/ : the most popular framework but less easy to use (it's my point of view)

You can also look at the documentation on MSDN (the param to use is *query)*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems.aspx